# Работа с ВКонтакте со стороннего сайта

Tags: php, вконтакте, javascript

Есть сайт ВКонтакте.
Как удаленно, с моего сайта, производить действия на ВКонтакте, например, добавлять в друзья?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите документацию на [OpenAPI ВКонтакта](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=Open_API) и [описания методов API](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_API).

Для добавления друзей используется метод [`friends.add`](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=friends.add), но данный метод доступен только Desktop-приложениям, так что не факт, что Вам дадут такую возможность.

Answer (score 0):

Может, конечно, что-то упустил, но будто бы не все действия есть в доке. Там можно делать почти всё, что угодно, но конкретно добавлять в друзья не видел.
Но, например, [подписаться](https://dev.vk.com/widgets/subscribe) на автора можно по событию `widgets.subscribed`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]